# 1: What is a dataset in the context of machine learning?

Tags: dataset, data-collection

Define the Problem and Objectives: Before embarking on dataset creation, it's important to have a clear understanding of the problem you are trying to solve and the objectives of your machine learning project. This will help you define the scope of your dataset, determine the required data types, and establish evaluation metrics.

Data Collection: Data collection is the foundation of any dataset. Depending on your problem domain, data can be collected from various sources such as public repositories, APIs, web scraping, or user-generated content. It's essential to ensure that the data you collect is representative, diverse, and covers all relevant scenarios.

Data Preprocessing: Once you have collected the raw data, it's necessary to preprocess it to make it suitable for machine learning algorithms. Preprocessing steps may include data cleaning (removing duplicates, handling missing values), normalisation (scaling numerical data), encoding categorical variables, and feature engineering (creating new features from existing ones).

Data Labelling: If your machine learning task requires labelled data (supervised learning), you will need to annotate or label your dataset. Labelling can be done manually by experts or using crowdsourcing platforms. It's crucial to maintain labelling consistency and ensure high-quality annotations to prevent bias and improve model performance.

Data Augmentation:  To enhance the diversity and size of your dataset, consider applying data augmentation techniques. Data augmentation involves creating new samples by applying transformations such as rotation, translation, scaling, or adding noise to existing data points. Augmentation can help improve model generalisation and robustness.

Data Splitting: To evaluate your machine learning model's performance accurately, split your dataset into training, validation, and test sets. The training set is used to train the model, the validation set helps tune hyperparameters, and the test set provides an unbiased estimate of the model's performance.

Data Documentation and Metadata: Maintaining proper documentation and metadata about your dataset is essential for reproducibility and future use. Include information such as data source, collection date, preprocessing steps, labelling methodology, and any assumptions or limitations associated with the dataset.